# TinyMCE: Add complex format

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, tinymce

I want to add a format to the TinyMCE Editor for Joomla. It should be a format that displays a scalable graphical box around the content. Since the box must scale with the content, I cannot simply use one background box graphics. Instead, I must use graphics for the sides of the box which then can scale in x and y direction. In order to achieve this, I need to wrap the text into more than one div. Thus, I need a possibility to add a format that wraps the content into these divs. However, it seems that TinyMCE does only allow formats that wrap the content into one HTML element - but, as stated above, I need more than one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You may only define what html element you want to use to wrap the content in. The setting is called [root_block_element](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aforced_root_block)

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        forced_root_block : 'p'
});
```

Comment: Is it possible by adding own buttons?

Comment: well, you may fiddle with the contetn on button click, but the root element will have to stay the same - otherwise tinymce will take care of the wrapping.